# To avoid screen-reader text inside the button

Tags: google-chrome, screen-readers, wai-aria

I want to ignore text inside the button when Jaws reads, My Code is :

```
<span style="display:none;" id="text1">Hai</span>
<button aria-labelledby="text1"><span>firstbutton</span></button>
```

But Jaws reads as Hai first button

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `aria-hidden`? http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201205/hiding_visible_content_from_screen_readers_with_aria-hidden/

Comment: What's the point of the text if you don't want it read?

Comment: JAWS in fact announces your markup as "Hai firstbutton button". Still not the behavior you want, but you may want to revise your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This markup is announced at 'Hai button' in Voiceover OSX 10.8.4, ChromeVox 1.29.1, and JAWS 14.

```
<button aria-label='Hai'>
  <span aria-hidden='true'>firstbutton</span>
</button>`
```

Comment: This works for me in Mac but not in IPad. Pls help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can try: `<div id='first-button-label' class='visually-hidden'>Hai</div>
<button aria-labelledby='first-button-label'>firstbutton</button>`. (untested)

Comment: You're not going to get universal browser support from ARIA, fyi. If it's critical that the screen reader announce the button text as "Hai", you should consider making it the visible button text. It would be more conventional and would not create a divergent experience for blind users.