# Have screen reader (JAWS) read more than displayed button text

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I actually want to accomplish the opposite of:

[To avoid screen-reader text inside the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209327/to-avoid-screen-reader-text-inside-the-button)

For WCAG compliance, any HTML control (i.e. button) that opens a new browser window needs the screen reader to say so when the button gets focus.  However, I certainly don't want:

```
<button>Get Help ,opens in a new browser window</button>
```

The button text should just be "Get Help", but I need JAWS to verbalize more... any workable approaches out there for this?

Many thanks, -Pete

(FYI to moderators:  The existing "JAWS" tag refers to "Java API for WordNet Searching"... not the screen reader "Job Access With Speech".  We could probably use a new tag out there - I don't think I currently have the "stack overflow cred" to do that.  Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want to include the text but hide it from view.

```
<button>Get Help<span class="at">, opens in a new browser window</span></button>
```

"at" for "access technology".

With associated CSS of either:

```
.at {
   position:absolute;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

or, if you are concerned with horizontal scroll-bars in right-to-left languages or performance on mobile then you can use:

```
.at {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   height: 1px;
   width: 1px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
}
```

Read more at: http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

I should point out, people with other disabilities should be able to tell it opens in a new window as well. Perhaps consider adding a 'new window' icon?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use ABBR tag do add a description. You can see something [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/alt-techniques/)

Comment: <alt> and <abbr> get picked up by JAWS when associated with an image, or closer to my case, a button containing an image (instead of text).  When I use <abbr> with a button that has a textual label, only the label is verbalized by JAWS.  :(

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using `aria-haspopup="true"` as per the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-haspopup)?

Basically:

```
<button aria-haspopup="true">Get help</button>
```